# Create subset of data in r

Tags: r, subset, between

I have data with one column which specifies day of the year, the code below provides an example dataset. No errors are appearing with my code but when I look at the number of observations in 'df_2' and 'df_3' something is wrong. I can't work out what it is.

```
#Example data
height <- c(21,34,64,27,74,90)
weight <- c(1,45,2,46,3,7)
day <- c(23,67,34,1,90,54)
df <- data.frame(height,weight,day)

#get days between 30 &70, and between 80 & 100
df_2 <- subset(df, day>”30” & day<”70”)
df_3 <- subset(df, day>”80” & day<”100”)
df_4 <- rbind(df_2,df_3)
```

I have also tried typing it as a range eg: subset(df, day[30:70] but this produces an error.

Comment: have you tried removing the quotations from the numbers?

Comment: Don't use quotes around values supposed to be numeric.

Comment: You shouldn't be able to look at `df_2` and `df_3` because the code above would have generate an error and those two datasets wouldn't have been created. It looks like you've tried various different approaches and at some point you created those datasets. :) As people said above, you should remove the quotes, as you're dealing with numeric values.

Comment: Thanks. It's always the simple solutions...

Answer (score 0):

Please remove quotes as its they are numeric format

```
df_2 <- subset(df, day>= 30 & day <= 70)
df_3 <- subset(df, day>=80 & day<=100)
df_4 <- rbind(df_2,df_3)

> print(df_4)
  height weight day
     34     45  67
     64      2  34
     90      7  54
     74      3  90
```